# PHP Check filenames

Tags: php, filenames, file-exists

I've created a simple PHP script which reads .txt files (1.txt, 2.txt etc which each contain dummy text: "Test~Test test test test test test") and produces a html output of each file's content with a little html formatting.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {background-color: #80B2FF; font-family: arial,sans-serif;}
        .content {background-color: #ffffff; margin: 35px auto; max-width: 75%; padding: 35px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
for ($number = 3; $number>=1; $number--){
    $article = $number.".txt";
    $data = file_get_contents($article); //read the file
    $convert = explode("~", $data); //create array separate by new line
    echo '<div class="content">'.$convert[0].'<br/><br/>'; //write value by index 0
    echo $convert[1].'<br/><br/>'.'</div>'; //write value by index 0
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This currently works just fine. The problem is that if I was to create the file 4.txt, I would have to hard code the $number variable to 4.

I have tried to automatically initialise $number to the highest number.txt. I need help creating a loop which would use the file_exists() function to test if a file x.txt exists, if it does then increment x and test again. If it doesn't exist, the loop should instead break out and hence I could just say $number=x.

I hope this explanation is clear enough, thank you for your time.

Comment: First, use a database. It is much easier. Second, if you are keen on using this method, you could look at [`glob`](http://php.net/glob)

Comment: Use `glob()` to get a list of files from the directory and use that to work out which files to read.

Comment: What problem are you having writing the loop that uses `file_exists`? It seems trivial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `glob()`, your method is pretty bad:

http://php.net/glob or http://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_filesystem_glob.asp

What you want to do is `$arr = glob("*.txt");` and then loop through that array.

Comment: Just watch out for a caveat of glob... by default it does sort the files by name, but not in a sane way. For example, 1.txt,10.txt,2.txt,3.txt. To fix this, use natsort($arr); afterwards if your order is important.

Comment: @rjdown This is how *all* UNIX tools sort files, and has nothing to do with PHP's `glob()` function. It also makes perfect sense to sort files likes this, IMHO, since this is, well, how sorting works...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I am aware of that, I am simply pointing out that the results returned by this answer will not match the ordering in the OP's code so some fiddling is needed. In fact, looking again he would need to do array_reverse(natsort($arr)) !!

Comment: Thanks now it all works exactly as I intended, the updated PHP:<?php
$array=glob("*.txt");
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    $array[$key] = substr($val, 0, -4);
}
for ($number = max($array); $number>=1; $number--){
    $article = $number.".txt";
    $data = file_get_contents($article); //read the file
    $convert = explode("~", $data); //create array separate by new line
    echo '<div class="content">'.$convert[0].'<br/><br/>'; //write value by index 0
    echo $convert[1].'<br/><br/>'.'</div>'; //write value by index 0
}
?>